# Getting started with Flex3 

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flex3

I'm a little bit confused.
I want to start learn Flex3 with Eclipse and the FlexPlugin .
But I can't find the link.

Is the Standalone version of FlexBuilder free ?

How do i set up the Enviorement ?
Do i have to download the FlexBuilder ( free?)
Or do i have to download Eclipse and then add the plugin ( link ? )

Can anyone help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex Builder Standalone will work as is just download and use, but no version of flex builder is free, you get a trail version of 30 days or so.

For Flex Builder plugin version you need to first download Eclipse from eclipse.org and then download the  Flex plugin. On installation of the flex plugin, the wizard will prompt you to point it the eclipse (unzipped) location, it will take care of installing the plugins.

The plugin version is useful if you want to work on java based projects, if you just want to learn flex use Flex Builder Standalone version.

Answer (score 1):

Flex Builder is not free. You can use [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=FlashDevelop:About) together with [flex sdk](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk) (both are free) to get syntax highlighting and code completion in mxml/AS files.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can get hold of Flex Builder for free, assuming you fit into one of two categories, if you are unemployed or in education (educator or student)

See [freeriatools](https://freeriatools.adobe.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flex Builder is not free but you can download trial. Flex SDK is free though and will be enough at least for hello world examples.